# How to merge every second row in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I mean, how can I get from this:

A

B

C

D

E

F

a result like this:

ACE

BDF

This means I have a table and need the headlines (ACE) to be above the value lines (BDF). So the merge should skip a line then merge and then the same role should apply to the second and fourth rows, etc.
The file is over a million row, sadly.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: by using macro.

Comment: I tried, it just delete the rows.

Comment: Share your macro so we can see and help

Comment: I would, but I can't step into it. It's quite strange, that is so different from Ecxel. I only can recond and then save and reply. No editing mode :(.

Comment: No, I read that, and do not work for me. As that one do not skip rows and mine would. I tried to build it to skip one row before merge but it do not work out.

Comment: did you try the solution given in my answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm trying to set the second part up... it is real slow as the file is huge.

Comment: O.k. Hoewer I was hoping for a kind of solution what was in the (How to merge lines every 3 rows in Notepad++?) questions, just to adding some +1 or other kind of extracts to the following commands in replace: Find what: (.+)(\r|\n)+(.+)(\r|\n)+(.+) so avoid macro as I can't edit them.
Replace with: \1\t\3\t\5\t

Answer (score 1):

I would break my objective in two tasks:
1. Form ACE...
2. Form BDF...

> To form ACE.., record a macro and do following in sequence

`Home`
`Shift End`
`Right arrow`
`Ctrl + X`
`Down arrow`
`Ctrl + V`
`Backspace`

Repeat this until required.

This will complete your first task and the result will be the last line of the file..

> To form BDF.. It is more simple. point your cursor at B and Record macro:

`End`
`Delete`

Repeat till you reach result of the first task..

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-j is the shortcut key to merge two lines. 
You can record a macro to go to the next line, select, down arrow, CTRL-J, down arrow.

Then you can run the macro multiple times to merge a bunch. It's not elegant, but it gets the job done.